# How does Unix Command interpreted at OS level

Tags: unix, operating-system, command

I am new to Unix and wanted to understand under the hood working of Unix command. My question is whenever we type any command in shell, how are they interpreted at OS level.

Any help will be great. Thanks.

Comment: There is a dedicated StackExchange Unix site, not sure this belongs to  Stack Overflow... Otherwise, this is "just" a process. Read on about `fork()` and `execve()`, file descriptor inheritance, etc etc.

Comment: Depending on exactly how far down the rabbit hole you want to go, read a book. Or ten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the interpretation of commands is done by the shell, not the operating system.

As mentioned in a comment, the operating system provides system calls like fork() and execve() that allow the creation and manipulation of processes. There are also calls that control file descriptors so that inputs and output can be arbitrarily mapped. The operating system provides all of this functionality, but it is up to the shell (bash, csh, zsh, etc) to interpret commands and issue the correct system calls.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But can you explain how is it interpreted by shell? Can you provide a brief overview.